# example of Runnable anonymous class mocking that applies changes in the Outterclass?

Tags: android, mockito, runnable

In my android project, In my presenter, I'm running one background thread in a Runnable anonymous class which applies changes in presenter class member. When the thread ends it calls a callback.
Does anyone have an example of Runnable anonymous class mocking that applies changes in the Outer class?

Comment: Could you please show the code?

Comment: If you're trying to mock an anonymous Runnable, the trick about it is that it contains a hidden reference to the outer class that owns it. If you're passing in a mock Runnable, you'll need a reference to the outer class so you can simulate what the Runnable did, and you may need to relax field visibility (private to package private, for instance) so you can simulate the effect of the Runnable from outside the outer class. I agree with user8035311, it'll be much easier if you _show_ us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I was short on time so I couldn't publish my code. To answer my question I had to refactor my code and reduce the coupling between classes.

So, let me show you the conflictive part:

```
  @Override
  public void onResponse(final PresentationModel presentationModel) {
    presentationModelWrapper.clear();
    presentationModelWrapper.add(presentationModel);
    if(isViewAttached()){
      final SomeHandler someHandler = view.getSomeHandler();
      someHandler.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          //some code here
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

When the execution of someHandler ends I call the callback function which call a method of the presenter. Now, let me show you my solution:

```
@Mock
  private SomeContract.View view;
@Mock
  private SomeHandler someHandler;
@Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<SomeCallback> somethingCallbackArgumentCaptor;

  @InjectMocks
  private SomePresenter presenter;

 @Test
  public void loadSomething_shouldShowSomething() {
    // Given
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put(Constant.API_PARAMETER_QUERY, CUSTOM_QUERY);

    // Given a stubbed model
    model = new PresentationModel();

    //when
    presenter.loadSomething(parameters);
    //This part mock the someInteractor call
    when(view.getSomeHandler()).thenReturn(someHandler);
    verify(someInteractor).execute(anyMap(), somethingCallbackArgumentCaptor.capture());
    somethingCallbackArgumentCaptor.getValue().onResponse(model);
//we are on response my conflictive part
    verify(someHandler).execute(any(Runnable.class));
//I use presenter instead of ArgumentCaptor because handler has a presenter reference 
    presenter.onDatabaseOperationFinished();
    // Then
    SomethingUI uiModel = presenter.getUiModel();
    verify(view).showSomething(uiModel);
  }
```